# How to fix an undefined method when relationship is established in the controller and table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to build a simple rails app. I have generated a model called cities and added a migration for city_name. Leveraging a form, I was to create my first city. However, when I go show.html.erb - I'm not able see my city name. Instead I'm prompted with an error "undefined method `city_name' for nil:NilClass"

I have pasted all my relevant code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Cities Controller**

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @cities = City.all
    end    
    def new
    @city = City.new
    end
    def show
    end

    def create
    @city = City.new(city_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @city.save  

        format.html { redirect_to @city, notice: 'City was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @city }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @city.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    end

    private
    def city_params
      params.require(:city).permit(:city_name)
    end 
end
```

**Show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>
    <%= @city.city_name %>
  </strong>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Back', cities_path %>
```

**Cities Model**

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the mistake was, the issue is in the controller. I need to set up a before action and write out a method that would search for the param id of the specific city. My controller code is listed below for easy reference in case anyone else struggles with this.

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_city, only: [:show]
    def index
    @cities = City.all
    end

    def new
    @city = City.new
    end

    def show

    end

    def create
    @city = City.new(city_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @city.save  

        format.html { redirect_to @city, notice: 'City was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @city }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @city.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    end

    private
    def set_city
      @city = City.find(params[:id])
    end

    def city_params
      params.require(:city).permit(:city_name)
    end



end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you build a simple ruby on rails then here's show def

```
  def show
@service_order = ServiceOrder.find(params[:id])

  end
end
```

Comment: Come on - the least you can do is adapt this code so that it actually answers the question.